# wordpress isnt loading in the_content() or footer.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a custom theme, but have run into some problems. For your information my files are as seen below:

```
themes/
    aq-aquatics/
       css/
       img/
       js/
       footer.php
       functions.php
       header.php
       index.php
       page-homepage.php
       page-wide.php
       style.css
    index.php
```

This is my header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"  />
<meta name="author" content="Matthew Smart">
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>

<?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
<header>
    <div class="header-top text-right">
        <div class="container">
            <span style="margin-right:40px;">Tel: 01922 418050</span><span>Email: sales@hollybush-garden.com</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-content" style="min-height:86px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1" style="position:absolute;top:11px;z-index:1000;">
                    <img src="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.png" width="108" height="100" alt="a&d logo"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 text-right" style="margin-left:132px;">
                    <nav class="navbar">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div>
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="width:inherit; border-bottom:none !important;margin-top:31px;">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">At A & D
                                            <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Aquatics
                                            <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="#">Tropical</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Pond</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Marine</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Cold water</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Aquatics Sundries</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Valencia Wharf Coffee Shop</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Opening Times</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="purple-line" style="margin-bottom:25px;"></div>
</header>
```

This is my page.wide.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Wide Page
*/
get_header();

?>


<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        //
        // Post Content here
        the_content();
        //
    } // end while
} // end if
?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And this is my footer.php

```
<footer>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        A&D AQUATIC & GARDEN CENTRE | WEBSITE DESIGN BY <span>MATTHEW SMART</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
        <ul>
            <li>TERMS AND CONDITIONS</li>
            <li>PRIVACY POLICY</li>
            <li>COOKES</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</footer>


</div><!-- End WRAP -->
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the page i am trying to test is using the wide template. I have put some dummy text into the editor and clicked publish.

Now when i try to visit the page the first thing i can see is part of the header. The browser then takes another 5 seconds and loads the navigation which is in my header.php file.

It seems to just ignore everything from the page template and afterwards. So the_content() pulls nothing through and the footer doesn't get displayed.

I have been comparing these files with other themes i have created and cannot seem to find a cause.

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is missing the_post().

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        //
        // Post Content here
        the_content();
        //
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post

This is necessary to let WordPress know you are inside the loop, and retrieve the requested post's data. The footer isn't loading because the page is erroring out when it calls the_content() and cannot deal with this function outside the loop.

According to WordPress [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) the_content "must be within The_Loop."